# Speed Up Apache Drill Query

Tags: apache-drill

**Hello**

`I am using Drill in Window 10 in embedded mode having latest version (1.7).
I am writing one select Query for Sql Server Database.`

**Query is:-**

```
SELECT CAST(T1.`ID` AS BIGINT) AS `ID`, CAST(T1.`AttributeID` AS BIGINT) AS `AttributeID`, T1.`String_Value` AS `String_Value`, CAST(T1.`Numeric_Value` AS BIGINT) AS `Numeric_Value`, T1.`MetaData` AS `MetaData`, T1.`DataType` AS `DataType`, T1.`CreatedTime` AS `CreatedTime`, CAST(T1.`CreatedBy` AS BIGINT) AS `CreatedBy` FROM demoplugin.`dbo`.`ProductValues` AS T1
```

**Result:-** **`It returns 1,113,843 rows in 107.126 Second.`**

***My question is is there any way to speed up my drill, so that query execute fast(in less second).?***

Comment: Please post the query plan and the source of data.